# How to add keywords in app description in google play console?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I tried to add keywords in app description like this-
keyword,keyword,keyword,keyword ...
But they rejected my app to publish in google play store.

**Showing that there is issue with your app**
Your app contains content that doesn’t comply with the Metadata policy.
Specifically:
The app title or description does not accurately describe the app’s functionality.

**Issue details**
We found an issue in the following area(s):
Full description (en_US): keyword,keyword....

Comment: Yes, adding keywords is not allowed at all. All the ASO services out there are a big scam.